# How to Configure the nuget.config file for xamarin project is VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I am building a Xamarin app in Visual Studio, but am having problems with the source control, which I think is because I don't have a nuget.config file.

Firstly, do I need one per solution or one for the whole project, or alternatively just on in the PCL etc.

Secondly (the main question), is it possible auto-generate these files based on the nugets you currently have installed? Also, when these are updated, is it possible to keep the nuget.config file up to date?

## Update:

In Visual Studio the `Manage NuGet packages for Solution` option which was present in past versions is not displayed for my project, not sure if this is the software version or the projects configuration.

Comment: please check this http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/04/21/nuget-tip-3-manage-packages-at-the-solution-level/

Comment: @AmitTiwari Thanks for this - it's a good resource, but in VS2015 I don't have an option `Manage NuGet packages for Solution`, why is this?